# How to get displayed object color (no css color available) with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

From an ASPX page I am trying to get the colors of various small boxes. They indicate a status (red, yellow, green) and are updated by a script. Different to any other content I can not get the color from these boxes, as they do not contain any color information:

```
<span id="live_states681" style="left: 284px;width: 10px;position: absolute;height: 10px;top: 80px;z-index: 837;"><canvas id="live_states681_canv" width="10" height="10" style="position: absolute;"></canvas></span>
```

There is no CSS data I can use.
In Chrome I can find "color: rgb(0, 0, 0); -internal-root-color html" under the color information.

Any idea how to get the color via Selenium in Python?